# Adobe Font Metrics for Standard PDF Fonts in CP1252

Tags: pdf, fonts, iso-8859-1, cp1252

I need the metrics for the 14 standard PDF fonts.

I've download the following from Adobe, but it appears to use ISO-8859-1 encoding, rather than CP1252: 
https://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/pdf/Core14_AFMs.zip

So it's missing code points 127 to 142 (for example, the ellipsis character).

Where can I download CP1252 versions of these Type1 fonts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Core 14' PDF fonts don't know of 'CP1252' encoding (nor of 'ISO-8859-1').

They use their own encodings and encoding names, called: *StandardEncoding*, *MacRomanEncoding*, *WinAnsiEncoding* and *PDFDocEncoding* (where the *WinAnsiEncoding* largely maps to CP1252).

The font metric files you linked to are all for the *Extended Roman* character set (except the two symbol fonts *Symbol* and *ZapfDingbats*, which use a 'Special' character set) and the *AdobeStandardEncoding* encoding scheme (again except the two fonts mentioned before, which use a font specific scheme each).

The metrics for the ellipsis character is ***NOT MISSING***, but it ***IS*** contained in 12 of these 14 AFM files (again, the two symbol fonts don't contain this glyph, and therefor also don't list its metrics).

To learn more about the encodings and character sets used by the 14 core PDF fonts, please refer to *Annex D (normative)*, titled *'Character Sets and Encodings'*, of the [**PDF-1.7 specification**](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: So basically I need to create a look up table between the font metrics in each `.afm` file and the glyphs defined for `CP1252` -- [WinAnsiEncoding](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/vim/vim-44/runtime/print/cp1252.ps). Using **ellipsis** as an example, in `helvetica.afm`, its index is `188`, and in `WinAnsiEncoding`, its index is `133`. To get the bounding box for this glyph, I could do something like `m#; N ellipsis ; B (.+?) ;#` and then `$cp1252[133] = $1`